# Connect Two Document Libraries Together - Advice Needed!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-type, document, 2016

I need to sync two document libraries together. (Its easier for me to explain the situation).

I'm designing a IT SharePoint site. Each team in IT will have their own team site and document libraries for technical documents and non technical docs (user guides). Non IT staff will have access to a self service IT site where these user guides will be used /accessed.

What I would like to set up, IT team member uploads a user guide to their team site. The document (depending on its classification type) will be uploaded to the IT self service site document library and be searchable by the users. Is this possible? Which ways could I accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to combine libraries column. then you can use lookup column. Lookup column provide you all columns of the another document column on first library. if something else then describe more.

Comment: Hi, this method won't work as the lookups only include information on the current site. Not the site collection - "Lookup (information already on this site)"

Answer (score 2):

Why not you create a document library with document sets
(1 document set for each department) and provide unique permission based upon department by creating group. It will be easy rather creating multiple document library.

OR

create a document library with Folders
(1 Folder for each department) and provide unique permission based upon department by creating group. It will be easy rather creating multiple document library.

Comment: I just thought it would be simpler for the users if Each team had their own library to put content into and then in turn, would automatically be populated in the public library for non IT users to browse.

Comment: to move/copy files from one document library(IT user) to another document library(Non IT user) automatically, you need to create workflow or go for custom code for event reciever.

Answer (score 0):

What @anil pal says is right.  This is not possible OOTB because it is a best practice to only have one copy of each document in your environment both for economy of database space and to reduce complication with identifying the correct file.

Therefore, you have 2 options.  Option #1 make one self service library for all and have your IT teams upload to there and link to that location on their own sites.  Option #2 have each IT team manage their own content on their own site but allow all users read access to each team's individual library (only).  You would need to make a link directory or aggregate search on the main site.